# Why aren't my nav links showing up now on my navbar?

Tags: html, css

My navbar had been working fine, until I tinkered with trying to change my navbar to fixed and now it's not working. Not sure what I did wrong, but none of my links are showing up at all. I removed the code I had originally put so it should be working now but it's not. I also tried doing the special reload, forgot what it's called, to get rid of an old cached file, but still not working. Only thing that shows up is my logo on my nav bar, that's it.

**base.html/navbar**

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}

{% load unread_messages_counter %}

<!-- Navbar is located in this file -->


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>Base</title>
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

    

    

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>
    <style>
    <!-- Add this tag -->
    {% block styles %}

    {% endblock %}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
     
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class= 'navbar-brand'  href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}"><h5 style="color:red"></h5> </a>
        <button class= "navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse"  >
          <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto" >


            {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
                {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}


                    <li class="nav-item"  >
                        <a class=  "notification" style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css" > 
                        <span>Inbox</span>
                        <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% else %}

                    <li class="nav-item">

                        <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">    
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

 </nav>
```

**style.css**

```
.navbar-nav  li{
  padding-left:35px;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  color:yellow;
  
  width: 100%;
}





/* Modify the backgorund color */ 
.navbar-custom { 
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid pink
} 


.jumbotron{

  background-image: url("/static/images/jumbo.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 350px
}




.notification {

  
  
  text-decoration: none;
  padding:50;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  
}




.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.social a{
  font-size: 4.5em;
  padding: 3rem;

}


.fa-facebook{
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-twitter{
  color:#00aced;
}
.fa-goggle-plus-g{
  color:#dd4b39;
}
.fa-instagram{
  color:#517fa4;
}
.fa-youtube{
  color:#bb0000;
}

.fa-facebook:hover,
.fa-twitter:hover,
.fa-instagram:hover,
.fa-instagram:hover,
.fa-youtube:hover{
  color: #d5d5d5;
}



footer {
  padding-top:3.5rem;
  color:blue;
  background-color: #ffffff

}

hr.light{
  border-top:1px solid red;
  width:75%;
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom:1rem;

}

hr.light-100{
  border-top:1px solid #;
  width:100%;
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom:1rem;

}

body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: arial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
    .card-container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 430px;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  }
    .upper-container{
    height: 150px;
    background: #7F00FF;
  }
    .image-container{
    background: white;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    transform: translate(100px,100px);
  }
    .image-container img{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
    .lower-container{
    height: 280px;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
    .lower-container h3, h4{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: .6;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
    .lower-container h4{
    color: #7F00FF;
    opacity: .6;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
    .lower-container p{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: gray;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
    .lower-container .btn{
    padding: 12px 20px;
    background: #7F00FF;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
  }
  .lower-container .btn:hover{
    background: transparent;
    color: #7F00FF;
    border: 2px solid #7F00FF;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot really help you without a working HTML structure that can reproduce your current situation. But why are you doing this ? `margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;` ?

Comment: @MihaiT I went ahead and added a picture of the issue.

Comment: Picture doesn't  help if i cannot reproduce the issue. Did you try removing those margins ?

Comment: @MihaiT I did do that, and it didn't matter. How can I add a working html structure?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe instead of `.navbar-nav  li`, try `.navbar-nav  li a` in your css